# Tensorflow - Reduce session.run() overhead

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, profiling, reinforcement-learning, overhead

I am currently programming a little reinforcement learning project with tensorflow. When I profiled a training run I noticed that more than 65% of the run time is needed only to sample the actions.

Note: In reinforcement learning you have to sample actions at each step of the trajectory. That's why it is not possible to sample in batches.

I run this graph on a GPU, so I suspect the overhead that comes with calling the session.run() method and thus copying the data from the RAM to the GPU each time causes this kind of overhead.

My question is: Is there a way to reduce the overhead that comes with calling the session.run() method this many time? Is it possible to run the sample_op (forward pass) on CPU, and run the training on GPU?

Many thanks in advance!

This is the code of my RL policy:

```py
class Policy:
def __init__(self, sess, state_size, action_size, lr, alpha_entropy,  epsilon):
    self.sess = sess
    self.action_size = action_size
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        with tf.variable_scope("Policy"):
            self.state_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, state_size], name="state_ph")
            self.action_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, action_size], name="action_ph")
            self.advantage_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="action_ph")

            with tf.variable_scope("pi"):
                self.pi, self.mean_action = self._create_model(trainable=True)
                self.pi_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="Policy/pi")

                self.sample_op = self.pi.sample()

            with tf.variable_scope("old_pi"):
                self.old_pi, _ = self._create_model(trainable=False)
                self.old_pi_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="Policy/old_pi")

            with tf.variable_scope("loss"):
                prob_ratio = self.pi.prob(self.action_ph) / self.old_pi.prob(self.action_ph)
                surrogate = prob_ratio * self.advantage_ph

                clipped_surrogate = tf.minimum(surrogate,  tf.clip_by_value(prob_ratio, 1.-epsilon, 1.+epsilon)*self.advantage_ph)

                self.pi_entropy = self.pi.entropy()

                tf.summary.scalar("entropy", tf.reduce_mean(self.pi_entropy))

                self.loss = -tf.reduce_mean(clipped_surrogate + alpha_entropy * self.pi_entropy)

                tf.summary.scalar("objective", self.loss)

            with tf.variable_scope("training"):
                self.gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, self.pi_vars)
                #self.gradients = [tf.clip_by_value(g, -1000, 1000) for g in self.gradients]
                #self.gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(self.gradients, GRADIENT_NORM)
                grads = zip(self.gradients, self.pi_vars)
                self.optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).apply_gradients(grads)

                [tf.summary.histogram(v.name, g) for g, v in grads]

            with tf.variable_scope("update_old_policy"):
                self.update_oldpi_op = [oldp.assign(p) for p, oldp in zip(self.pi_vars, self.old_pi_vars)]

            self.summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all(scope="Policy")

def _create_model(self, trainable):
    layer_names = ["l1", "l2", "l3", "l4"]

    l1 = tf.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", name=layer_names[0], trainable=trainable, kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),)(self.state_ph)
    l2 = tf.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name=layer_names[1], trainable=trainable, kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),)(l1)
    l3 = tf.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", name=layer_names[2], trainable=trainable, activity_regularizer= tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.001),kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),)(l2)
    mu = tf.layers.Dense(self.action_size, activation="tanh", name=layer_names[3], trainable=trainable, kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),)(l3)

    log_sigma = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.fill((self.action_size,), 0.), trainable=trainable)

    distribution = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=tf.exp(log_sigma))

    tf.summary.histogram("log_sigma", log_sigma)
    tf.summary.histogram("mu", mu)

    for name in layer_names:
        with tf.variable_scope(name, reuse=True):
            tf.summary.histogram("kernel", tf.get_variable("kernel"))
            tf.summary.histogram("bias", tf.get_variable("bias"))

    return distribution, mu

def sample_action(self, state):
    return self.sess.run([self.mean_action, self.sample_op], feed_dict={
        self.state_ph: state
    })

def train(self, states, actions, advantages):
    _, summaries =self.sess.run([self.optimize, self.summary_op], feed_dict={
        self.state_ph:states,
        self.action_ph: actions,
        self.advantage_ph: advantages
    })
    return summaries

def update_old_pi(self):
    self.sess.run([self.update_oldpi_op])
```

Profiling result:

[image]

Comment: You can have sampling and training in different devices if you want, although I'm not sure why you prefer that. It will cause an overhead if you want to use the same variables (parameters) from two devices, no matter where they are placed they will have to be copied over all the time. If you really need that, maybe you could have the variables on GPU for training and then CPU copies of them, and synchronize them once per training step or set of steps (I think you're doing something like that with `old_pi`?). That way you don't make copies from GPU on every sample.

Comment: I might be completely off with my observations, but: 1) all your variables are placed on cpu:0 2) even if it was possible to split forward and backward pass operations NNs use intermediate output and weights on both paths and you will have to copy proportional amount of information back and forth

Comment: @jdehesa I tried to implement a solution where I have a separate network that runs only on CPU for sampling and gets it weights copied periodically. However the problem remains. I really suspect that session.run() calls introduce a large overhead by itself, regardless if the network runs on GPU or CPU.